# lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle does not work with symfony 5.2

Tags: symfony, jwt, symfony5, lexikjwtauthbundle

I'm trying to install and configure `lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle` in symfony 5.2 project.
When I applied the following documentation https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#installation, it gave me this error:

> You must either configure a "public_key" or a "secret_key".

So, I applied another configuration :

```
lexik_jwt_authentication:
  secret_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY)%'
  public_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
  pass_phrase: '%env(JWT_PASSPHRASE)%'
  token_ttl: '%env(JWT_TTL)%'
```

and in my .env file I have this :

```
###> lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle ###
JWT_SECRET_KEY=%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/private.pem
JWT_PUBLIC_KEY=%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/public.pem
JWT_PASSPHRASE=mypassphrase
JWT_TTL=3600 # 1 hour expiration
###< lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle ###
```

Then I ran these commands to generate the keys (the keys are generated successfuly under my directory `config/jwt`):

```
- openssl genpkey -out config/jwt/private.pem -aes256 -algorithm rsa -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:4096
- openssl pkey -in config/jwt/private.pem -out config/jwt/public.pem -pubout
```

But, when I run this command to check if it works, I have this error :

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8000/api -d '{"username":"johndoe","password":"test"}'
```

> "An error occurred","status":400,"detail":"Invalid
> JSON.","class":"Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\BadRequestHttpException

And I obtain this error when I test this method in my controller as explained here: https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/7-manual-token-creation.md :

> "Cannot autowire argument $user of
> "App\Controller\DefaultController::getTokenUser()": it references
> interface "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface"
> but no such service exists. Did you create a class that implements
> this interface?"

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Services\JWTTokenManagerInterface;

class ApiController extends Controller
{
    public function getTokenUser(UserInterface $user, JWTTokenManagerInterface $JWTManager)
    {
        // ...

        return new JsonResponse(['token' => $JWTManager->create($user)]);
    }
}
```

**Is this bundle compatible with Symfony 5.2 and how can I resolve this problem ?**

Comment: It's amazing what sort of info you can discovery from the [source code repository](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle).  Also, the controller code you posted will not work under 5.x and will in fact throw a completely different class not found exception.  Maybe start with a clean 5.2 project, install the bundle then work you way through the docs step by step.  Then try to deal with your legacy code.